# situation of simplex in the same layer with the same barycenter

Tags: convex-optimization, simplex, polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

a layer in $R^{k}$ is sum of entries of a integer point. for example $(1,5,3)$ lie on the layer $1+5+3=9$.

suppose we have a simplex whose vertices are permuted an integer point. for example a simplex with vertices $(3,2,1,4)$, $ (4,3,2,1)$, $(1,4,3,2)$, $(2,1,4,3)$ in $R^{4}$.

my question is that can we find any condition for the vertices of new simplex who can have smaller simplex in its interior(in the same layer)? for example in $ R^{4}$  there is an example in $R^{4}$ that: adding 1 to the biggest entry and subtracting 1 from another entry.

I think in higher dimension we need to change more coordinates. am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be bigger than $\sqrt{2}$